# How to search specific columns (First and Last names) and replace all special Characters (non Alpha characters)

Tags: notepad++

I have large .txt files (sometimes over 10K lines) that contain 5 fields that are both numerical and Alpha fields.  The issue I am having is that the second and third fields are first and last names and the other fields are all numbers.
Is there a way that I can only search the columns for first and last names and replace any numbers or special characters with spaces?  Also, is it possible to list all of the characters I need to replace all at once with the Find and Replace function limiting to the 2 columns?

Here is a sample of the files;

```
200068897        LLC                  BLUES 25              6085264         20240209
201499188        LLC                  ACTION!!               6085269         20240209
201499188        LLC                  ACTION#              6085269         20240209
```

Comment: How are your columns separated? By spaces? Because in that case your first line has 6 columns.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^\d+\h+|\G(?!^))[a-z]*\K[^a-z](?=.*\h+\d+\h+\d+\h*$)`
- Replace with:    # a space
- **UNTICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
  ^             # beginning of line
    \d+         # 1 or more digits
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  |             # OR
    \G          # restart from last match position
    (?!^)       # not at the beginning of line
)               # end group
[a-z]*          # 0 or more letters
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
[^a-z]          # a character that is not a letter
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    .*          # 0 or more any character
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    \d+         # 1 or more digits
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    \d+         # 1 or more digits
    \h+         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  $             # end of line
)               # end group
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]